# How to bundle only functions imported in object spread using webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a react application created with create-react-app, and the webpack config has been ejected so I have access to that too.

I just find out that when I import one of the functions from lodash like below.

```
import { cloneDeep as _cloneDeep } from "lodash";
```

When I run the build, everything from lodash is bundled in the js file.

```
npm run build
```

And I find this is the same for other libraries as well.

Is there a way to bundle only the functions that I have imported so that I can reduce the bundle size?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is tree shaking feature from [rollupjs](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en). According to this [article](https://medium.com/modus-create-front-end-development/webpack-2-tree-shaking-configuration-9f1de90f3233), webpack 2 also have similar feature perhaps you want to try.

Comment: Thanks! I get it solved with the webpack tree shaking feature. Have to set modules to false as shown [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-env/#modules) so that babel will not transpile import to commonjs syntax. For webpack 4, more information can be found [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/)